# Two way data binding in Angular with POST request from modal

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-bootstrap

**Hello all,**

I have an issue with data binding. I am using the angulat boostrap modal to send a post request to a Laravel API and I am receiving the proper information. I am pushing the result in an array, the array is updated but the DOM isn't.

Can you please point me in the right direction?

**This is the form I'm using in the modal:**

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="ProjectsController">
<div class="row title">
    <h2>Project Info <small>Please fill in all the fields</small></h2>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <form ng-submit="createProject()">
        <div class="form-group">
            <!-- <label for="project-name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Project name:</label> -->
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="project-name" class="form-control" placeholder="Project name" ng-model="new_project.name" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <!-- <label for="project-name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Project name:</label> -->
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <textarea name="description" id="project-description" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Project description"  ng-model="new_project.description" required></textarea>
                <!-- <input type="text" name="description" id="project-description" class="form-control" placeholder="Project description"  ng-model="new_project.description" required> -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">Submit project</button>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-left">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**This is where I want to update the DOM and where I trigger the dialog**

```
<div class="create-proj" ng-controller="ProjectsController">
        <button id="saveProfileButton" class="primaryButton" ng-click="createModalNewProject()">Create Project</button>
    </div>
<ul class="projects" ng-controller="ProjectsController">
                <li ng-repeat="project in Projects">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <h4><span class="title" ng-bind="project.name"></span>
                                <span class="dropdown left-navigation-project-settings-icons dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"></span>
                            </h4>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

**This is the controller in angular:**

```
angular.module('app.dashboard.projects')
    .controller("ProjectsController", function($scope, $modal, $resource, ProjectsFactory){
        $scope.Projects = {};
        $scope.new_project = {};

    $scope.createModalNewProject = function(){
        // console.log("bla");
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'js/modules/projects/views/new-project.html',
            controller : ModalController
        });
    };

        $scope.createProject = function () {
            ProjectsFactory.create($scope.new_project).$promise.then(function(data){
                $scope.Projects.push(data.projects);
            });
        };

        $scope.updateList = function(){
            $scope.Projects.push(data.projects);
        };



        showAll();
        function showAll(){
            ProjectsFactory.show().$promise.then(function(data){
                return $scope.Projects = data.projects;
            });
        };
    });
```

**This is the factory that I'm using:**

```
angular.module('app.dashboard.projects')
    .factory('ProjectsFactory', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('api/v1/projects/:projectId', {}, {
            show: { method: 'GET' },
            create: { method: 'POST' },
            update: { method: 'PUT', params: {id: '@id'} },
            delete: { method: 'DELETE', params: {id: '@id'} }
        })
    });
```

Reference to the modal module:
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: I think the first segment of code is not what you meant to paste there (as it's basically the same as the second and doesn't correspond with the header). Additionally adding a JSFiddle might help people investigate the problem.

Comment: Just to check when you do `$scope.Projects.push(data.projects);` is `data.projects` one project or an array? And is `$scope.Projects` an array of projects? -- Actually, you've initialized `$scope.Projects = {};` What are you doing pushing stuff onto an object?

Comment: @towr, you were right. I edited the post because I missed some pieces of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why data are not updated is because modal is isolated scope and you don't pass the data to the modal scope. Example how you can solve it:

```
angular.module('app.dashboard.projects')
    .controller("ProjectsController", function($scope, $modal, $resource, ProjectsFactory) {
        $scope.createModalNewProject = function() {
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'js/modules/projects/views/new-project.html',
                controller: function($scope, $modalInstance, items) {
                    $scope.items = items;

                    console.log($scope.items);
                    $scope.ok = function() {
                        $modalInstance.close();
                    };

                    $scope.cancel = function() {
                        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                    };
                },
                resolve: {
                    items: function() {
                        return ProjectsFactory.show().$promise.then(function(data) {
                            return data;
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        };
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea. Unfortunately it doesn't update the DOM and the scope variable. Can you please take a look once more?

Comment: Hi here is an example and it works:
http://plnkr.co/edit/fCfvcnwP9JSHbX5L2Vuu?p=preview

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the example.
I actually need the response from the resource outside the dialog.

Comment: Can you create your example in plnkr ? So i can modify for you.

Answer (score 1):

After some digging I changed the controller and now it looks like this. I forgot to broadcast the response from my ajax call so I can show it outside the modal scope. Thank you for all your help.

```
var CreateController = function($scope, $modalInstance, items,ProjectsFactory, $rootScope ){

    $scope.new_project = {};
    $scope.ok = function() {
        $modalInstance.close();
    };

    $scope.cancel = function() {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };

    $scope.createProject = function (items) {
        ProjectsFactory.create($scope.new_project).$promise.then(function(data){
                if(data.error){
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('project.update', data.result);
                }
                $rootScope.$broadcast('project.update', data.result);
        });
    };
};

app.controller("ProjectsController",['$scope','$modal','$resource','ProjectsFactory','$timeout','$rootScope', function(
        $scope,
        $modal, 
        $resource,
        ProjectsFactory,
        $timeout,
        $rootScope
){

    $scope.Projects = [];

    $scope.$on('project.update', function(event, data) {
        $scope.Projects.unshift(data);
    });

    function showAll(){
        ProjectsFactory.show().$promise.then(function(data){
            $scope.Projects = data.result;
        });
    }

    showAll();

    // $scope.addProject = function(){
    //     $scope.Projects = $rootScope.Projects;
    //     $timeout(function(){$scope.$apply()},500);
    // }

    $scope.createModalNewProject = function(){
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: '/js/modules/projects/views/new-project.html',
            controller: CreateController,
            resolve: {
                items: function() {
                    return ProjectsFactory.show().$promise.then(function(data) {
                        return data.result;
                    });
                }
            }

        });
    };


    $scope.safeApply = function(fn) {
        var phase = this.$root.$$phase;
        if(phase == '$apply' || phase == '$digest') {
            if(fn && (typeof(fn) === 'function')) {
                fn();
            }
        } else {
            this.$apply(fn);
        }
    };


}]).controller('CreateController',['$scope','$modalInstance','items','ProjectsFactory','$rootScope',CreateController]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the flow is wrong, In your controller do something like this

`angular.module('app.dashboard.projects')
    .controller("ProjectsController", function($scope, $modal, $resource, ProjectsFactory) {
$scope.Projects = ProjectsFactory.get();
}`